# Prove that $U_{1} \oplus U_{2} \oplus U_{3}= \mathbb{C^{7}} \rightarrow \exists U_{j=1...3} | dim U_{j} \geq 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My work so far:

There exist 3 basis of each of the three subpsaces, all containing vectors independent in the larger subspace of $\mathbb{C}$, such that the length of each basis summed will equal 7. Then I showed the maximum sum of the length of the three basis when the length of each was less than 2 (2+2+2)=6

Is it fair to say that the direct sums imply that the length of each basis summed is equal to the larger space? Or is that a jump that cannot necessarily be made, or perhaps should be proved (classroom setting, I am a student)?

Prove that $U_{1} \oplus U_{2} \oplus U_{3}= \mathbb{C^{7}} \rightarrow \exists U_{j=1...3} | dim U_{j} \geq 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right.

Saying that $U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus U_3 = \mathbb C^7$ is equivalent to saying that every $v \in \mathbb C^7$ can be written in the form
$ v = u_1 + u_2 + u_3,$
where $u_1 \in U_1$, $u_2, \in U_2$, $u_3 \in U_3$, and there is only one unique way of doing so.

Given bases $\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{k_1} \}$ for $U_1$, $\{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_{k_2}\}$ for $U_2$ and  $\{ \gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_{k_3} \}$ for $U_3$, it follows that $\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{k_1} , \beta_1, \dots, \beta_{k_2}, \gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_{k_3} \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb C^7$. Indeed, from we just said, every $v \in \mathbb C^7$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{k_1} , \beta_1, \dots, \beta_{k_2}, \gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_{k_3} \}$ in a unique way, which is precisely what it means for $\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{k_1} , \beta_1, \dots, \beta_{k_2}, \gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_{k_3} \}$ to be a basis.